# Records filtering

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk

I have this kind of file `file-1`:

```
1       1       1.1552422143268792
1       2       1.1552422143268792
1       3       1.1552422143268792
1       4       1.1552422143268792
2       1       2.1906014042706916
2       2       2.1906014042706916
2       3       2.1906014042706916
2       4       2.1906014042706916
2       1       4.1906014042706916
2       2       4.1906014042706916
2       3       4.1906014042706916
2       4       4.1906014042706916
3       1       3.1876823799523781
3       2       3.1876823799523781
3       3       3.1876823799523781
3       4       3.1876823799523781
4       1       0.6213184222668061
4       2       0.6213184222668061
4       3       0.6213184222668061
4       4       0.6213184222668061
```

and I have antoher file too `file-2`

```
1
2
4
```

I would like to filter those records from `file-1`, in which the values of the first colum are the same as in `file-2`, so I would like to get this output

```
1       1       1.1552422143268792
1       2       1.1552422143268792
1       3       1.1552422143268792
1       4       1.1552422143268792
2       1       2.1906014042706916
2       2       2.1906014042706916
2       3       2.1906014042706916
2       4       2.1906014042706916
2       1       4.1906014042706916
2       2       4.1906014042706916
2       3       4.1906014042706916
2       4       4.1906014042706916
4       1       0.6213184222668061
4       2       0.6213184222668061
4       3       0.6213184222668061
4       4       0.6213184222668061
```

Can anybody help a little?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{f2[$1];next}$1 in f2' file-2 file-1
```

Comment: Looks much better as a one-liner than 3-liners. Hope you are ok with me updating it. :)

Comment: Hi @JaypalSingh, yes, no problem! I prefer the previous code indentation, but I don't have problems with that one too :)

Answer (score 4):

Very simple using `join`:

```
join file-1 file-2
```

The files must be sorted for `join` to work. The sort is based on *text*, not numeric values, so you may need to sort into a temp file first. Something like:

```
sort file-2 > sorted.tmp
sort file-1 | join - sorted.tmp
```

Comment: Instead of sorting into a temp file you could use command subtitution, if your shell is `bash`: `join <(sort -n file-1) <(sort -n file-2)` - it's actually doing the same thing but is a bit cleaner.

Comment: @Sorpigal Not `sort -n`; `join` matches arbitrary strings, not numbers, so a lexicographic sort is needed. A numeric sort won't be reliable in general.

Comment: Based on his sample data I don't believe we need to worry about in general in this case.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber Would this work? `join <(sort file-1) <(sort file-2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-f` option in grep to read patterns from a file. But first you must change the patterns so that they match the first field only. You can do this by using `sed` to add a `^` to the beginning and a space to the end of each pattern in file-2, and using process substitution in your command.

The complete command is:

```
grep -f <(sed -e "s/^/^/g" -e "s/$/ /g" file-2) file-1
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
 sed 's/.*/\/^& \/p/' file-2 | sed -nf - file-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do in `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} !($1 in a){next}1' file-2 file-1
```